# ChromeでHTMLファイルをPDF保存時のページサイズ指定が動作しない

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

Chrome上でHTMLファイルを開いて、PDFに保存するというのをやりたくて、
下記コードを書きましたが、コード中のappState内の"pageSize"をA3、A5、レターサイズと
どんなに値を変えて指定しても、出力されたPDFファイルのページサイズがA4となってしまいます。
appState内の他のプロパティ"isLandscapeEnabled"や"isHeaderFooterEnabled"の値を変えると、出力されたPDFは設定通りになっていて、動いています。
コントロールパネル→地域→形式(F)を日本に設定した場合は、出力されたPDFファイルのページサイズがずっとA4で、
米国に設定すると、ずっとレターサイズになってしまいます。

python初心者で、まだほとんど理解できていません。このコードのどこかが悪いでしょうか？
ご教授をよろしくお願いします。

環境
Python 3.9.6
selenium 3.141.0
Chrome 94.0.4606.71
ChromeDriver 94.0.4606.61
windows10

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import json
import time

def PrintSetUp():
    chopt=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    appState = {
        "recentDestinations": [
            {
                "id": "Save as PDF",
                "origin": "local",
                "account":""
            }
        ],
        "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
        "version": 2,
        "isLandscapeEnabled": False,
        "pageSize": 'A3', 
        "marginsType": 0,
        "scalingType": 3 , 
        "scaling": "100" ,
        "isHeaderFooterEnabled": False, #ヘッダーとフッター
        "isCssBackgroundEnabled": True, #背景のグラフィック
    }
    
    prefs = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState':
             json.dumps(appState),
             "download.default_directory": "~/Downloads"
             }
    chopt.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
    chopt.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
    return chopt

def main_WebToPDF(BlogURL):
    chopt = PrintSetUp()
    driver_path = "C:/Work/pythonTest/Ver94/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe" #webdriverのパス
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=chopt)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) # 秒 暗示的待機 
    driver.get(BlogURL) #ブログのURL 読み込み
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located)  # ページ上のすべての要素が読み込まれるまで待機（15秒でタイムアウト判定）
    driver.execute_script('return window.print()') #Print as PDF
    time.sleep(10) #ファイルのダウンロードのために10秒待機
    driver.quit() #Close Screen
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    BlogURLList=["file://C:/Work/pythonTest/1_pdf.html",
                 "file://C:/Work/pythonTest/2_pdf.html",
                 "file://C:/Work/pythonTest/3_pdf.html"]
    for BlogURL in  BlogURLList:
        main_WebToPDF(BlogURL)
```

Comment: 何かこの記事が詳しく解説してそうなので読んでみてはどうでしょう？ [Python - WebページをPDFで自動保存する ~Selenium pdf Print Option~ HTML to PDF](https://degitalization.hatenablog.jp/entry/2021/03/13/102805) 他にPythonのパッケージを使って何とかしたような記事があります。[Selenium print PDF in A4 format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68164550/9014308)

Comment: 今回のコードはその「WebページをPDFで自動保存する」サイトを参考に(ほぼそのまま)作らせていただきましたが、ページサイズの指定が効いていないようです。ほかのパッケージは試していませんが、試してみたいと思います。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

最近、ページサイズ変更ができました。
A2で印刷する場合には、"mediaSize"に以下のJSONを入力する感じです。

Chromeの印刷画面自体が、HTMLで描画されているので、画面中に右クリックで、「検証」を選択すると、要素が出てきますのでそこを参考にすると、用紙サイズの指定ができると思います。

```js
{
    "height_microns":594000,
    "imageable_area_bottom_microns":0,
    "imageable_area_left_microns":0,
    "imageable_area_right_microns":420000,
    "imageable_area_top_microns":594000,
    "name":"ISO_A2",
    "width_microns":420000,
    "custom_display_name":"A2"
}
```